# Passing hidden value using jQuery in MVC

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc

My MVC Controller passes a Model to view in the following form

```
    public class LibaryModel
    {
        public int LibaryId { get; set; }

        public string[] Books { get; set; }
    }
```

This is my LibraryView.cshtml

```
 @model IEnumerable<LibaryModel>
    <table id="myTable" class="table-bordered">
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th>Libary Id</th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
            @foreach (var library in Model)
            {
                <tr>
                    <td>@library.LibaryId</td>
                </tr>
            }
        </tbody>
    </table>
```

Now, On clicking the library id, I need to show another div with the list of books in that library. I am able to get the row number and column number of click event, but I am not able to figure a way to get the list of books in the libary from jQuery. Is there any pattern to solve this?

```
 $("#myTable td").on('click', function () {
        var column_num = parseInt($(this).index()) + 1;
        var row_num = parseInt($(this).parent().index()) + 1;

    });
```

Comment: There's not a pattern for this. You just need to create an Action method in your controller and pass it the ID from the row that was clicked. Either return that div, or return the data as a JSON block and populate the div client side.

Comment: @krillgar: The model already has all the information required. Calling another action will have to re fetch all the data from database, which is costly.

Comment: Well it all depends on how you want to do it. You can store the entire model as a JSON block inside a script tag and them use jQuery to either populate a hidden div, or construct a new div. Or, you can not include the books in your initial data load, hit an action method and return a new View/Partial View with the book data.

Comment: What is the model for your view? You've not actually shown it. Is it `IEnumerable<LibraryModel>`?

Comment: @Sippy: Yes it is IEnumerable<LibaryModel>. I have updated the question with Model for the view

Comment: The view shows you not even rendering anything for the `Books` collection. Either render then inside hidden elements that are shown on the `click` event, or (better) use ajax to call a controller method that returns the collection of books for the selected `LibraryId`. Getting the row and column number is of no use in this situation. And if your table really only contains one value, using a table is not really appropriate.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest using the LibraryId in a function on a click event in your td.

```
foreach (var library in Model)
{
    <tr>
        <td onclick="getHiddens(@library.LibraryId)">@library.LibaryId</td>
    </tr>
}
```

And give your books' hidden inputs a class that contains its library's LibraryId

```
for (var i = 0; i < library.Books.Length; i++)
{
    <input type="hidden" class="book@library.LibraryId" value="@library.Books[i]" />
}
```

And then sending that LibraryId into a function as an argument that gets all matching inputs by class, and does something with the input's value, like for this example, loading it into a div.

```
var getHiddens = function (libraryId) {
    var books = document.getElementsByClassName("book" + libraryId);


    var bookDiv = document.getElementById("bookDiv");

    bookDiv.innerHTML = "<ul>";
    for (var i = 0; i < books.length; i++) {
        bookDiv.innerHTML += "<li>" + books[i].value + "</li>";
    }
    bookDiv.innerHTML += "</ul>";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Please check my code .

```
 @foreach (var library in Model)
            {
                <tr>
                    <a href="javascript:void(0)" 
                    onclick="GoToInsured('@library.LibaryId');">
               </tr>
            }

function GoToInsured(LibaryId)
{
 //This LibaryId is current selected row ID.You can open new Diva per 
  LibaryId. You can get Library details as per LibaryId and you can display 
  that data on Popup or any place you want.
}
```

Tell me you have any query regarding my code .

Thanks .